# Python print returns None

Tags: python, printing

I was working out the solution to a problem when I came across the following...

I had started by creating a variable, `test`, and initializing it to a list.

```
test = [3, 2, 1]
```

After playing around with `.sort()` and calling it upon my list, `test`, I tried to use print as follows:

```
print test.sort(reverse = True)
```

The output was `None` and I was just curious as to why exactly this is.

Comment: In the future, why not try `help(list.sort)` or `help(test.sort)`, or look it up [in the online help](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#mutable-sequence-types)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`sort()` modifies the list in-place, and returns `None`. This is unlike the `sorted()` function, which returns a reference to the sorted list.

It *could* return a reference as well (like JavaScript's `sort()`), but it doesn't. It's a *design decision*.

Comment: In the opinion of many, a `poor` design decision, but a design decision nonetheless.  :)

Comment: @Gerrat: And in the opinion of many, a very good design decision. And in the opinion of a few, a very design decision made for the wrong (at least conscious) reason that happens to be very good anyway. :)

Comment: @abarnert:  I suppose I can't fault the `BDFL` for the few decisions I dislike, given the overall beauty, simplicity, and utility of the language I enjoy so much.

Answer (score 1):

Sort works in place. It does not return new list.